# Forming clusters using pre-defined groups on Google-Apps-Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am currently working on creating a distance matrix using Google Apps Script/javascript. At the moment, I currently have 50 addresses that I would like to sort into groups, based on their state codes.

I have filtered out the relevant state codes (Sheet name: 'Filtered States'). And I have filtered out the addresses that match those state codes (Sheet name: 'Filtered Addresses').

Now, my aim is to produce a script that compares the list of addresses against the state codes and sorts the addresses into arrays, depending on if the state codes match the filtered state codes.

I've written a script so far that is meant to crosscheck the addresses against the filtered state codes. However, the results provide a list of the addresses without any sorting taking place.

```
function maps(origin, destination) {
  var driving = Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING
  var transit = Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.TRANSIT
  var modeSet = driving
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .setMode(modeSet)
  .setOptimizeWaypoints(true)
  .getDirections()
  var result = directions
  return result;         

}

function sorting() {
 //get distance
  var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maps");
  var relstatecodes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Filtered States");
  //relstatecodes are the filtered states that will form the clusters
  var reladdresses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Relevant Addresses");
  //reladdresses are the full addresses that match the filtered states
  var lastrow = relstatecodes.getLastRow();
  var lastrow2 = reladdresses.getLastRow()
  var range = relstatecodes.getRange(3,1, lastrow-1,1);   //list starts from row 3
  var range2 = reladdresses.getRange(2,3, lastrow2-1,3); //list starts from row 2 col3
  var statecodes = range.getValues();
  var stateaddresses = range2.getValues()
  var storage = []

  for (var y = 0; y < statecodes.length; y++) //sorting addresses into clusters
  {
    var sort = []
    for (var x = 0; x < stateaddresses.length; x++) //checking if addresses match the filtered state codes
    { if ( x[0] == y[0]) {
      sort.push(x[0])
      storage.push(sort)
    }
    }
  }
 console.log(storage);
}
```

The link to the spreadsheet I'm using is:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Y1br0klimT8aAf74oJjo0VnROCt7iHTFP16wvDx1TI/edit?usp=sharing

What I want is to have a 'storage' array which hosts all the sorted addresses. I can then use this to carry out further distance calculations. I apologise in advance if any of this is confusing.

Edit: The results should look like:

```
['1000 S Fremont Ave #5, Alhambra, CA 91803, United States',
'4021 Rosewood Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90004, United States' , '919 S Grand Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90015, United States', 
'17335 N Palm Bluffs Ave, Fresno, CA 93711, United States',
'6363 Sunset Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90028, United States'], ['1365 N Scottsdale Rd, Scottsdale, AZ 85257, United States',
'350 W Washington St, Tempe, AZ 85281, United States',
'501 E. Orange St., Tempe, AZ 85287, United States']...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, this code can help you to sort the addresses in the way you want:

### Code

```
function sorting() {
 //get distance
  var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maps");
  var relstatecodes = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Filtered States");
  var reladdresses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Relevant Addresses");
  var lastrow = relstatecodes.getLastRow();
  var lastrow2 = reladdresses.getLastRow()
  var range = relstatecodes.getRange(3,1, lastrow-2,1);
  var range2 = reladdresses.getRange(2,3, lastrow2-1,1);
  
  var statecodes = range.getValues();
  var stateaddresses = range2.getValues();
  var reladdresses = [];
  var clusterObj = {};
  
  // Let´s iterate through the array with the state codes
  statecodes.forEach(function(el){
     clusterObj[el] = [];
    // We take all the state addresses
    for(var i in stateaddresses){
      // We check if the state address includes the state code 
      if( stateaddresses[i].toString().indexOf(" " + el + " ") > - 1){
         // If it is included then we build the JavaScript object
        clusterObj[el].push(stateaddresses[i][0]);
      }
    }
  });
  
   // Logger.log(clusterObj);
  
  // You can check in this way the addresses by state code
  Logger.log(clusterObj["AZ"]);
  Logger.log(clusterObj["CA"]); 
 
}
```

### Output

```
 [1365 N Scottsdale Rd, Scottsdale, AZ 85257, United States, 350 W Washington St, Tempe, AZ 85281, United States, 501 E. Orange St., Tempe, AZ 85287, United States, 2323 W 14th St, Tempe, AZ 85281, United States, 1555 W University Dr #103, Tempe, AZ 85281, United States,  2844 West Deer Valley Road, Phoenix, AZ 85027, United States]
[19-11-06 15:55:56:760 CET] [1000 S Fremont Ave #5, Alhambra, CA 91803, United States, 4021 Rosewood Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90004, United States, 919 S Grand Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90015, United States, 7335 N Palm Bluffs Ave, Fresno, CA 93711, United States, 6363 Sunset Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90028, United States, 9331 Mariposa Rd, Hesperia, CA 92344, United States, 2041 Business Center Dr, Irvine, CA 92612, United States, 5757 Plaza Dr #100, Cypress, CA 90630, United States, 257 Longford Dr #5, South San Francisco, CA 94080, United States, 151 Innovation Dr, Irvine, CA 92617, United States, 5 Hutton Centre Dr #500, Santa Ana, CA 92707, United States, 8620 Spectrum Center Boulevard Suite 600, San Diego, CA 92123, United States]
```

What I did was taking the array with the states codes and with those values, check if that word was inside the addresses in your `stateaddresses` and if the state code was there, add the address to `clusterObj`.

As a plus, I will leave this [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) documentation, just in case you want to check it, because it may be helpful in the development of your project.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly! Thanks for including the Best practices document as well, as the next step is to work on batch operations :)

Comment: Do you have any idea of how I would be able to produce separate arrays or dictionaries based on matching state codes? For e.g. All the addresses with an AZ code would be in an array that I could refer to later?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer as the correct one, I edited a little the code for what you requested

Comment: Thanks for editing the code. It now shows the clusters just the way I wanted.